# Sequential row numbers for MySQL results, when selecting from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, select

I know how to get sequential result numbers from a MySQL query selecting from a single table. What I'm having a hard time figuring out is how to do it when selecting from multiple tables.

For instance:

```
SELECT fieldA, fieldB FROM tableFoo, tableBar WHERE condition = 'true'
```

How can I modify this to add the row numbers for the results? (It's probably simple, but for some reason I can't wrap my head around what to do.)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps (untested):

```
SET @row_number:=0;
SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number, A.fieldA, A.fieldB FROM 
(SELECT fieldA, fieldB FROM tableFoo, tableBar WHERE condition = 'true') AS A 
ORDER BY row_number;
```

Here is an anonymized example with an existing db:

SQL statement:

```
SET @row_number:=0;
SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number, A.id, A.sname, A.fname FROM 
(select h.id, right(md5(m.sname), 5) sname, right(md5(m.fname), 5) fname from member m 
join household h on h.id = m.household_id where h.id > 9000
order by h.id, m.sname, m.sname) as A limit 20;
```

Results:

```
1   9001    7f9f6   424d5
2   9002    5bc65   cc2c0
3   9002    5bc65   8b13a
4   9002    5bc65   addb2
5   9002    5bc65   14f57
6   9002    5bc65   95924
7   9003    5adb1   cc0e0
8   9003    5adb1   ac703
9   9003    5adb1   e2ae7
10  9003    5adb1   fe3dc
11  9003    5adb1   d5eb3
12  9003    5adb1   d24a0
13  9004    35fc7   cd978
14  9004    35fc7   41fd1
15  9005    41b5c   32fd4
16  9005    41b5c   8c1bb
17  9005    41b5c   6119a
18  9006    dd3fd   941a2
19  9007    345a4   a7d5e
20  9007    345a4   4c161
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work for me. I managed to solve the issue with a different workaround, but would still be interested in figuring this out as it would be a significantly cleaner solution than what I finally ended up cobbling together.

Comment: In what way did it not work? You can modify the `ORDER BY` to fit your needs. Can you post your workaround as an answer?

Comment: I've added an example using an existing db.

Comment: First, thank you for helping out with this. The problem is that I'm working within a templating system that allows use of MySQL, but doesn't really output any useful information when things fail. I could have done some troubleshooting from outside the system, but was running out of time and had to make it work any way I could. The workaround I used was within the templating system and not relevant to this question. It is messy and adds unnecessary overhead, so I plan to come back to this within a week or two, and will play with this answer further and post anything relevant I find.